# How to maintain user control values in view state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I want to maintain user control values in view state

I tried textbox,dropdown values are maintaing in view state

But BasicDatePicker value is not maintaing in view state I'm getting null value

Code:

.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="addnewtext" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="addnewtext_Click"  width="76px" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveVisa" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveVisa_Click" />
```

.aspx.cs

```
 private const string VIEWSTATEKEY = "ContactCount";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Set the number of default controls
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY];

            //Load the contact control based on Vewstate key
            LoadContactControls();
        }
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

        LoadContactControls();
    }


    private void LoadContactControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY].ToString()); i++)
        {
          rpt1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx"));
        }
    }

    protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadContactControls();
        ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY].ToString()) + 1;

    }
    private void saveData()
    {
        foreach (var control in rpt1.Controls)
        {
            var usercontrol = control as AddVisaControl;

            string s = usercontrol.TextVisaNumber;
            string date = usercontrol.ExpiryDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveData();
    }
   }
```

.ascx

Here I added the assembly for BasicDatePicker

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddVisaControl.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="Pyramid.AddVisaControl" %>
   <%@ Register assembly="BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" namespace="BasicFrame.WebControls" tagprefix="BDP" %>
   <div id="divreg" runat="server">
   <table id="tbl" runat="server">
   <tr>
   <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td> Visa Number:</td>
   <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
   <td> Country Name:</td>
   <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px" runat="server">         </asp:DropDownList></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td> Type of Visa:</td>
   <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> </td>
   <td> Type of Entry:</td>
   <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> Expiry Date</td>
   <td><BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="basicdate" runat="server"></BDP:BasicDatePicker></td>
   <td>
   <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
```

.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtUser.Text = Request.Form[txtUser.UniqueID];
    dropCountry.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropCountry.UniqueID];
    dropVisa.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropVisa.UniqueID];
    dropEntry.SelectedValue = Request.Form[dropEntry.UniqueID];
    //Here I'm getting null value  
    basicdate.SelectedValue = Request.Form[basicdate.UniqueID];
}

public string TextVisaNumber
{
    get { return txtUser.Text; }
    set { txtUser.Text = value; }
}

public DateTime ExpiryDate
{
    get
    {
        return basicdate.SelectedDate;
    }
    set
    {
        basicdate.SelectedDate = value;
    }
}
```

In the below image when I give for textbox,dropdown and date picker then I click Add button controls are added textbox,dropdown value is there but datepicker value is disappear

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value in a hidden control and reinstate the value into the appropriate control on postback, if jquery is involved, which I'm guessing it is, it often forgets it's value on postback regardless of viewstate being enabled etc.

Have a look [at this blog post](http://www.himanshusaxena.net/asp-net-text-box-with-jquery-ui-date-picker-value-lost-on-a-post-back/) to set the datapicker value on ready using hidden field values.

Heres the code from the above blog post:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableMonthlyNotifications" runat ="server" CssClass="cell-Text" Text="Enable monthly notifications." />
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="txtMonthStartDate">Specify start date for monthly notification</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthStartDate" runat="server" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMonthStartDate" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="txtMonthEndDate">Specify end date for monthly notification, or leave blank if no end date.</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthEndDate" runat="server" Enabled="true" > </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMonthEndDate" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery to Initialize Datepicker with Alternate Field

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnMonthStartDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtMonthEndDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnMonthEndDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtQuarterStartDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnQuarterStartDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtQuarterEndDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnQuarterEndDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtHalfYearStartDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnHalfYearStartDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtHalfYearEndDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnHalfYearEndDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtYearStartDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnYearStartDate]' });
   $("[id$=_txtYearEndDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnYearEndDate]' });
}
```

jQuery Code to set Datepicker date again on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  //Initializing the datepicker

  $("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: '/icon_cal.png', altField: '[id$=_hdnMonthStartDate]' });

  //Code to set the datepicker's date again after post back
  if(!($("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").attr("Value") == undefined))
  {
    if($("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").attr("Value").length > 0)
    {
        $("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").datepicker("setDate",new Date($("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").val($("[id$=_txtMonthStartDate]").attr("Value"))));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done that before, too. It's not the safest or best practice, though. Once I finally got viewstate working, it was a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So, this code is going to be a bit different than yours, but I know it works. I've been running it for weeks here at work. I've got a pre-render, create viewstate, and load viewstate. Whenever one of my values changes, I save it to the private property I have set.

```
    //Global ViewState Variables
    private DataTable networksInfo;
    private string HHmm;
    private string Window;
    private string ZoomFactorTop;
    private string ZoomFactorBottom;
    protected Boolean autoRefresh; 

    /// <summary>
    /// This page prerender allows me to save viewstate objects before anything bad
    /// happens. It's going to save any data that needs to persist across postbacks,
    /// since the page refreshes with an autorefresh. Whenever updated, the ViewState
    /// will also need to be updated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the ViewStateObjects before the page is rendered.
        ViewState.Add("networksListVS", networksInfo);
        ViewState.Add("HHmmVS", HHmm);
        ViewState.Add("WindowVS", Window);
        ViewState.Add("ZoomFactorTopVS", ZoomFactorTop);
        ViewState.Add("ZoomFactorBottomVS", ZoomFactorBottom);
        ViewState.Add("AutoRefresh", autoRefresh);
    }

    protected void Create_ViewState(DateTime now)
    {
        //Populate Dropdown handles the initial value for networksInfo, but none of the others are

        //Set ViewState Vars' initial values
        if (ViewState["HHmmVS"] == null)
        {
            int HH = now.Hour;
            int mm = now.Minute;

            Change_Time(HH, mm);

        }
        if (ViewState["WindowVS"] == null)
        {
            //The default time window to view is 6 hours
            Window = "6";
        }
        if (ViewState["ZoomFactorTopVS"] == null)
        {
            //The default zoom factor is Window + 0
            ZoomFactorTop = "0";
        }
        if (ViewState["ZoomFactorBottomVS"] == null)
        {
            //The default zoom factor is Window + 0
            ZoomFactorBottom = "0";
        }
        if(ViewState["AutoRefresh"] == null)
        {
            autoRefresh = true;
        }
    }

    protected void Load_ViewState()
    {
        //Before updating the charts, we know that this is a postback and that the viewstate shouldn't
        //be null, but check anyways, just to be sure
        if (ViewState["networksListVS"] != null)
        {
            networksInfo = (DataTable)ViewState["networksListVS"];
        }
        if (ViewState["HHmmVS"] != null)
        {
            HHmm = (String)ViewState["HHmmVS"];
        }
        if (ViewState["WindowVS"] != null)
        {
            Window = (String)ViewState["WindowVS"];
        }
        if (ViewState["ZoomFactorTopVS"] != null)
        {
            ZoomFactorTop = (String)ViewState["ZoomFactorTopVS"];
        }
        if (ViewState["ZoomFactorBottomVS"] != null)
        {
            ZoomFactorBottom = (String)ViewState["ZoomFactorBottomVS"];
        }
        if (ViewState["AutoRefresh"] != null)
        {
            autoRefresh = (Boolean)ViewState["AutoRefresh"];
        }
    }
```

One of my variables is, in fact, a calendar object. The way I've got it working, is that, if the user chooses an older time, they don't want the page to refresh and the auto-refresh turns off.

If that's not a concern for you, the easiest thing to do is similar to what you're doing, which is to just save a state that represents a datetime object.

Now, from the stuff I've read, you need a pre-render (though this can be done in page load), a create viewstate (which could also be done there), and a load viewstate. The thing I'm seeing is that you may want outer variables, rather than get / set, kind of things to hold these values, because when I save my viewstate, it looks more like this:

```
                ZoomFactorTop = "0";
                ZoomFactorBottom = "0";

                //Save the changes just made to the objects the ViewState needs access to
                SaveViewState();
```

Hope that helped some!